# delete pointer that is assigned from another pointer, should i delete the other one again?

Tags: c++, pointers

so, here is my example to explain this question

```
void * p1;
int * p2, * p3;

p2 = new int;
p1 = p2;
p3 = (int *) p1;
```

to free the memory, are the following 3 lines equivalent to each other?

```
delete p2;
delete p3;
delete (int *) p1;
```

the reason i am using such is that i want to pass a pointer between functions without knowing its type, for instance i define a void pointer and changes its value by calling other functions as follow:

```
void * p1;
func1(p1); //in this function, p2 = new int and  p1 is assigned as p1 = p2;
func2(p1); //in this function, p1 is assigned to another pointer: int * p3 = (int *)p1;
```

then, i called func3 to release the memory

```
func3(p1); //delete int * p1
```

after calling func3, do i have to deal with p2 in func1 anymore?

thanks!

Comment: One `delete` pre `new`. One `delete []` pre `new []`. In this case you should use smart pointers.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, all 3 `delete`s are equivalent.  It's important to note that in the posted example, all 3 pointers point to the same thing.  This means if you `delete` one of them, you should not `delete` the others as the memory they point to has already been released.

If you do try to `delete` something that has already been released, you'll evoke Undefined Behavior.  If you're lucky your program will crash, but anything could happen.

Answer (score 8):

The question contains a misconception: you don't *delete* the *pointers*. You delete what they *point to*.

And you cannot delete a *same thing* more than once.

Think to three people pointing their fingers towards a same box. One of them says "throw *it* away". Once it has been thrown, they will remain with their finger still pointing in the same direction towards an empty space. With nothing more to throw away.

Answer (score 3):

You have only one allocation, so only one deletion is necessary. You have three items that allow you to find that memory (your pointers), so any will do for releasing it back to the O/S. Once released back to the O/S be careful not to use any of the old pointers, as they still hold the old address of your now freed memory. Going and using freed memory is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all three are equivalent.  The only thing you might want to do after calling delete is to set the pointers to nullptr so you can tell they are no longer valid:

```
p1 = nullptr ;
p2 = nullptr ;
p3 = nullptr ;
```

Remember that pointers *point to memory*.  When you do this:

```
p2 = new int;
```

You are saying 'declare me some new memory and hold it's address in p2'.  Now you can access that memory using p2.

When you do this:

```
p1 = p2;
```

You are saying 'I want p1 to point to the same memory that p2 is pointing to'.  You now have two pointers *pointing to the same memory*.

If you call delete on any one of the pointers it will delete that memory, and all of those pointers will now be pointing at the same released memory (i.e. they are now invalid).

The usual thing to do after releasing memory is to let the pointer variables go out of scope or set them to nullptr so that you can detect they are no longer valid.

Comment: semantic nitpicking: `0` is not `NULL` is not `nullptr`. It's `nullptr` that should be used, or `NULL` if using an old version of C++ prior to C++11.

Comment: True. I was writing this prior to using C++11 and was still used to `#define NULL 0`