# Can I delete a memory previously allocated dynamically, but with a different pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I was making a program for linked list in C++. To implement the concept, I created a pointer 'start' globally, pointing to the first element of the list.

After completion of the program I tried to delete all memory allocated dynamically to prevent memory leaks, by accessing successive nodes using the start and another locally declared pointer 'p'. 
Here, I used a pointer pointing to the same correct addresses,  but this pointer was not the one used for memory allocation, but was declared locally like any normal pointer.

My question is - Is it possible to delete the dynamically allocated memory by using the normal pointers pointing to the same location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete pointer that is assigned from another pointer, should i delete the other one again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259305/delete-pointer-that-is-assigned-from-another-pointer-should-i-delete-the-other)

Comment: Don't think of a pointer as pointing to an address, think of it as being an address (and it's pointing to the object at that address). If you're going to demolish the house at 35 Main Street, it doesn't matter how the address was communicated to you, it's still the same house.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Could you smash up 37 as well? Then the sunrise will be visible from number 36.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. This is valid:

```
int* p = new int;
int* q = p;
delete q;
```

The equivalent when using [new[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new):

```
int* p = new int[123];
int* q = p;
delete[] q;
```

Substitute `int*` with your pointer type. Whether to set the pointers to `nullptr` afterwards is up for debate.

Comment: Note that const int* q = p; delete q; also works, although I'd love to see a standard ref for that.

Comment: @Bathsheba Indeed. At first glance it might seem counter-intuitive but I guess `const` says _immutable_ not _can't be deleted_.

Comment: @Bathsheba C++14 [expr.delete]/2 final note

Answer (score 1):

So long as the pointer has the same **type and value**<sup>1</sup> as the one you got back from `new`, yes you can use that as the `delete` argument.

Also, remember to use `delete[]` if you used `new[]`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Qualifiers* (`const`, `volatile`) don't matter. Note that you can also use a pointer to a base class with a virtual destructor.

Comment: "same type"   :  Base class with virtual destructor also included as same type

Comment: @UKMonkey, pinched that, and wiki'd to maintain a clear conscience.